# XNA: Draw Bounding Box around Sprite

Tags: xna, 2d, xna-4.0

I'm just starting with XNA and I wanted to draw Debug Lines around my Texture/Sprite to help me.

Is there an easy way to do it with SpriteBatch?
I haven't used the GraphicsDevice yet to draw....

Thanks!

Comment: Just google search draw lines spritebatch... Basically it works by streching and rotation 1x1 texture

Comment: so i have to add a 1 pixel texuture to my content? Is there an easier way perhaps?

Comment: You can dynamicaly create it when creating spring batch (i have subclass SpringBatchEx), new Texture2D() then SetData and set white color, it will be in some of google results :)

Comment: Me and a friend have made an open-source project that helps with drawing lines, rectangles, and other "primitives" in XNA: https://bitbucket.org/jcpmcdonald/2d-xna-primitives/wiki/Home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php/Drawing_2D_lines_without_using_primitives

I would suggest to create subclass of SpriteBatch that would have DrawLine and DrawRectangle function and in constructor create 1x1 texture.

Comment: Im testing out that method but doesn't work.. need to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [forum post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/615135-wireframe-in-xna-2d/) in which the poster details how he is making spriteBatch draw in wireframe mode.

Basically you just need to change your draw code to this;

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,BlendState.Opaque);
RasterizerState state = new RasterizerState();
state.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = state;

spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White);

spriteBatch.End();
```

And obviously change "spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White)" to be a loop drawing all of your sprites.

Comment: doesn't seem to show me anything, but maybe my Rectangle for my sprite is out of screen..

Comment: Maybe, just try rendering with the line ...RasterizerState = state; commented out. Then you should just be rendering as normal.

Comment: The most important thing, basically, is to use SpriteSortMode.Immediate and spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = FillMode.WireFrame; The rest of your rendering code should stay the same.

Comment: I didn't see Immediate.. I'll try again